# Performance of metal function multiple call

Tags: ios, swift, metal

i make rigid body simulation for iPhone/iPad with using Apple Metal. To do this, i need to make many calls of kernel functions, and i see, that it takes a long time, opposite to CUDA for example. 
I implemented Metal kernel function call, like it describes in Apple tutorial

```
let commandQueue = device.newCommandQueue()

var commandBuffers:[MTLCommandBuffer]=[]
var gpuPrograms:[MTLFunction]=[]
var computePipelineFilters:[MTLComputePipelineState]=[]
var computeCommandEncoders:[MTLComputeCommandEncoder]=[]

//here i fill all arrays for my command queue
//and next i execute it 

let threadsPerGroup = MTLSize(width:1,height:1,depth:1)
let numThreadgroups = MTLSize(width:threadsAmount, height:1, depth:1)

for computeCommandEncoder in computeCommandEncoders
{
    computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(numThreadgroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerGroup)
}

for computeCommandEncoder in computeCommandEncoders
{
    computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
}

for commandBuffer in commandBuffers
{
    commandBuffer.enqueue()
}

for commandBuffer in commandBuffers
{
    commandBuffer.commit()
}

for commandBuffer in commandBuffers
{
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
}
```

I am do up to few dozens metal kernel functions every frame, and it works too slow. I tested it with empty kernel functions - and it shows me, that the problem are in Swift part of execution. I mean, when i want to execute kernel function in CUDA, i just call it like usual function and it works very fast. But here i must make many actions for every execution of every function every frame. May be i don't know something, but i want create all additional objects one time, and then just make something like

```
 commandQueue.execute()
```

to execute all kernel functions.

Am i rights in my actions to execute many kernel functions, or there is some other way to do it faster?

Answer (score 11):

I have a few projects that use multiple shaders in a single step. I only create a single buffer and encoder but multiple pipeline states; one for each compute function.

Remember that `MTLCommandQueue` is persistent, so only needs to be created once, so my MetalKit View's `drawRect()` function is roughly this (there are more shaders and textures being passed between them, but you get an idea of structure):

```
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()

commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(advect_pipelineState)
commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, 
    threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(divergence_pipelineState)
commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, 
    threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)

[...]

commandEncoder.endEncoding()
commandBuffer.commit()
```

My code actually iterates over one of the shaders twenty times and still runs pretty nippily, so if you reorganise and to follow this structure with a single buffer and a single encoder and only call `endEncoding()` and `commit()` once per pass, you may see an improvement in performance.

*May* being the operative word :)